# 自分のレビュー待ち投稿があるときに、承認待ちレビュー数が表示される。

Tags: バグ, 仕様

例えばレビュー待ちの投稿がない状態で、レビューが必要な編集を2つします。
そうすると、レビュー待ち投稿が2つあることを示す数字が画面上部に表示されます。

しかし、その数字をクリックして実際に画面遷移すると、「もうこのカテゴリにはレビュー待ちの投稿はありません！」と表示されます。依然として承認待ちレビュー数は2のままです。

その後、レビューが承認されるとこの数字は0になります。（たぶん。2回現象として確認したので、間違いないのではないかと思います。）

こうした場合、自分が投稿した数はカウントしないというのが正しい実装な気がします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Shog9（Stack Exchangeのコミュニティーコーディネーター）の回答](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5763)によれば、これは今のところ[意図的な仕様](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/157841)だそうです:

### トップバーに表示される、レビュー待ち件数を示す数字

[image: トップバー]

これはサイト全体でどれくらいタスクが積まれているかを把握するためのものです。自分には処理できないタスク、例えば自分の編集リクエスト、スキップしたレビュータスクなども含まれています。

もしこの数字が毎日増えていっている場合は、コミュニティのバランスが崩れているということで、要注意です。

ここを各ユーザーのレビュー状況に合わせた数にするのは[とてもコストがかかる](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#comment758002_230726)らしいです。

### 実際のレビュー画面

こちらには自分がレビューできないものは表示されません。[レビューキューの一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review)に表示される数字も同様です。